# I need to search for a value from 1 worksheet on another worksheet, and if it finds it return a value that is in a column next to it?

Tags: google-sheets

I will post a link to my sheet, but in the aurora coop worksheet column b, I want to search for the value in column a in worksheet Dispatch column load num.  If it finds it I want to return the value of the column named customer back to the aurora coop worksheet in column b so I know who I assigned the load number too.  Can anyone help?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CXU8xjV1Zv8KBA2EHR08tGCkUxfturVKbbpmREQtP98/pubhtml

Comment: I found that the command =LOOKUP(A2,LOADNUM,CUSTOMER) works for 1 line, but it will only work on 1 line.  As i progress through the numbers the result on the line before will change to the next one.

Comment: The hyperlink  is broken

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column 'CUSTOMER' is col C of sheet DISPATCH and column 'LOADNUM' is col F of sheet DISPATCH, in B2 of sheet AURORA COOP, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(A2:A, {DISPATCH!F2:F,DISPATCH!C2:C}, 2, 0),))
```

Or, depending on your locale:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A); vlookup(A2:A; {DISPATCH!F2:F\DISPATCH!C2:C}; 2; 0);))
```

note: make sure all other formulas are cleared from col B.